# Magento Multi store with Multi language and Multi currency

Tags: magento-1.9, currency, multicurrency

I want to configure website for multi country – multi currency.

e.g. For USA /Canada , I want to set Select country – USA , Currency should auto switch to $ from base currency.

But product should should be limited compared to base website. Means limited products for country. How to configure please guide me..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

There are tons of tutorials on this subject on the web.

You can try [this](http://www.hostknox.com/tutorials/magento/multilingual-store) or [this](https://www.apptha.com/blog/how-to-create-multilingual-website-in-magento/)

To summarize the proccess:

1. Create a two store views and name them "Language 1" and "Language 2"
2. Install language packs for the languages you want or duplicate app/locale/en_US/* to app/locale/your_LUNGUAGE and translate the files yourself
3. In System->Config->General->General->Locale Options set the "Locale" you desire for each scope (store view)
4. In System->Config->General->Currency Setup set the "Base Currency","Default Display Currency" for each scope (store view)
5. You can Enable/Disable each product for each store view changing the scope and toggling its status.